# Checking against value in a STRING_TABLE in a WHERE clause

Tags: abap, opensql

I have a procedure with the parameter `IT_ATINN`:

```
IMPORTING 
    REFERENCE(IT_ATINN) TYPE  STRING_TABLE
```

`IT_ATINN` contains a list of characteristics.

I have the following code:

```
LOOP AT values_tab INTO DATA(value).
   SELECT ( @value-INSTANCE ) AS CUOBJ
   FROM  IBSYMBOL
   WHERE SYMBOL_ID = @value-SYMBOL_ID 
     AND ATINN ???                       "<======== HERE ???
   APPENDING TABLE @DATA(ibsymbol_tab).
ENDLOOP.
```

How can I check if `ATINN` (in the WHERE clause) is equal to any entry in `IT_ATINN`?

Comment: Initialize a [ranges table](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenranges_table_glosry.htm) from the contents of `IT_ATINN`, and use `AND ATINN IN ranges_table`. There is a special case if `IT_ATINN` is empty, the ranges table should contain `E CP *` (exclude everything). Note that it's a bad idea to have a `SELECT` inside a loop, you should use `FOR ALL ENTRIES` or a join on  a Global Temporary Table or any other solution to avoid the nested SELECT.

Comment: @SandraRossi Thanks. How can I achieve `( @value-INSTANCE ) AS CUOBJ` when changing to ` FOR ALL ENTRIES ` ? The first part of the WHERE would be `WHERE SYMBOL_ID = @values_tab-SYMBOL_ID ` but I don't seem to have access to `@values_tab` in the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want (and I assume you want dynamic SELECT fields) you [cannot use](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abapinto_clause.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_5@5@) inline declarations here, both in LOOP and in SELECT:

> The structure of the results set must be statically identifiable. The SELECT list and the FROM clause must be specified statically and host variables in the SELECT list must not be generic.

So either you use inline or use dynamics, not both.

Here is the snippet that illustrates Sandra good suggestion:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_value_tab,
        instance  TYPE char18,
        symbol_id TYPE id,
       END OF ty_value_tab.

DATA: it_atinn TYPE string_table.

DATA: rt_atinn     TYPE RANGE OF atinn,
      value        TYPE ty_value_tab,
      values_tab   TYPE RANGE OF ty_value_tab,
      ibsymbol_tab TYPE TABLE OF ibsymbol.

rt_atinn = VALUE #( FOR value_atinn IN it_atinn ( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = value_atinn ) ).

APPEND VALUE ty_value_tab( instance = 'ATWRT' ) TO values_tab.
LOOP AT values_tab INTO value.
  SELECT (value-instance)
    FROM ibsymbol
   WHERE symbol_id = @value-symbol_id
     AND atinn IN @rt_atinn
  APPENDING CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @ibsymbol_tab.
ENDLOOP.
```

Overall, it makes no sense select `ibsymbol` in loop, 'cause it has only 8 fields, so you can easily collect all necessary fields from `values_tab` and pass them as dynamic fieldstring.

If you wanna use alias CUOBJ for your dynamic field you should add it like this:

```
LOOP AT values_tab INTO value.
  DATA(aliased_value) = value-instance && ` AS cuobj `.
  SELECT (aliased_value)
...
```

Remember, that your alias should exists among `ibsymbol` fields, otherwise in case of static `ibsymbol_tab` declaration this statement will throw a short dump.